# Are there any reasons to avoid using tmpnam() to get a name for a temporary file?

Tags: c++, c, file-io

I was going to use `tmpnam()` to name a temporary file that will be renamed later, not deleted. But I found the following documentation and I'm now intrigued about the part that says

**"...naive programmers may think it a suitable name for a temporary file."**

From http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/tmpnam.3.html

> The tmpnam() function returns a pointer to a string that is a valid
>          filename, and such that a file with this name did not exist at some
>          point in time, so that naive programmers may think it a suitable name
>          for a temporary file.  If the argument s is NULL this name is
>          generated in an internal static buffer and may be overwritten by the
>          next call to tmpnam().  If s is not NULL, the name is copied to the
>          character array (of length at least L_tmpnam) pointed to by s and the
>          value s is returned in case of success.

Can someone explain why does the documentation say that?

I assume "it" refers to the name generated, and that only naive programmers would think it is adequate to name a temp file, otherwise why mention it? If it isn't an appropriate solution, why does it exist?

I would greatly appreciate if someone could clear it up.

Comment: Possibly because it's considered a security hazard? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299881/tmpnam-warning-saying-it-is-dangerous

Comment: It exists because it's part of the POSIX standard.  The deficiency, as described in the standards document, is "Between the time a pathname is created and the file is opened, it is possible for some other process to create a file with the same name."

Comment: @MarkPlotnick so if I use the new x subspecifier when opening the file, there should be no problem?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "new x subspecifier". Can you rephrase?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick It only opens a file for writing if it doesn't exist. Take a look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/. It says:  The new C standard (C2011, which is not part of C++) adds a new standard subspecifier ("x"), that can be appended to any "w" specifier (to form "wx", "wbx", "w+x" or "w+bx"/"wb+x"). This subspecifier forces the function to fail if the file exists, instead of overwriting it.

Comment: Using 'x' couldn't hurt, but it's likely better to use something like [mkstemp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mkstemp.html) even though this is at a lower level than stdio. If security is a concern, I think asking the experts on the [Information Security StackExchange site](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another program may create a file with exactly that name in the meantime. To be sure you can actually get a file with that filename the creation of filename and file itself should be an atomic, indivisible operation.

It's a bit theoretical as the time between the tmpnam() and actual creation is likely to be very short. But still it's possible.

Comment: No, it's not "a bit theoretical". If you do this wrong it's an easily exploitable security vulnerability.

Comment: Let me add to @R..’s comment: I have seen such an exploit demonstrated on stage; it is real. An attacking program predicts likely results of `tmpnam`, creates corresponding files, and allows the victim to open them. The attacker can then read any confidential information the victim program writes to the file, because the attacker has full permissions over the file. They can also modify it. This attack can reveal security keys and gain root access.

Comment: So making sure the file doesn't exist by calling fopen with "wbx" will solve the problem?

Comment: Probably, but it is imho better to avoid completely. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21295974/are-there-any-reasons-to-avoid-using-tmpnam-to-get-a-name-for-a-temporary-file/21296105?noredirect=1#comment32119731_21296105