# warning: the use of `tmpnam' is dangerous, better use `mkstemp'

Tags: linux, api, warnings, libc

*(Note: This is **not** a duplicate question)*

I'm using the libc function `tmpnam`, and getting the following warning:

```
warning: the use of 'tmpnam' is dangerous, better use 'mkstemp'
```

My question isn't "how to disable the warning", but rather "what function should I be using instead"? `mkstemp` doesn't help, because I'm not trying to create a temporary file - I'm creating a temporary *directory*. And AFAIK, there isn't an API function for that.

So if I'm not supposed to use `tmpnam`, what *am* I supposed to use?

Comment: If someone is looking to why the function is dangerous, see: [tmpnam warning saying it is dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299881/tmpnam-warning-saying-it-is-dangerous)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're looking for [`mkdtemp`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mkdtemp.3.html):

```
mkdtemp - create a unique temporary directory
```

e.g.,

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
...
char templatebuf[80];
char *mkdirectory = mkdtemp(strcpy(templatebuf, "/tmp/mkprogXXXXXX"));
```

using `strcpy` to ensure the parameter passed to `mkdtemp` is writable (c89), or

```
#include <stdlib.h>
...
char templatebuf[] = "/tmp/mkprogXXXXXX";
char *mkdirectory = mkdtemp(templatebuf);
```

with c99.

Since the feature is "new" (only standardized within the past ten years, though provided in the mid-1990s on Linux), you need to turn the feature on in the header files with a preprocessor definition (which may differ from one platform to another).  The simplest for Linux is to define `_GNU_SOURCE`, e.g.,

```
gcc -D_GNU_SOURCE -o foo foo.c
```

Comment: Instead of `strcpy`, you can use `char templatebuf[] = "/tmp/mkprogXXXXXX";`

Comment: How does c99 allow this constant assignment without it being non-writable?

Comment: It is an *initialization* of writable memory, not simply an *assignment*.  To verify my understanding of the standard, I checked with gcc using `-Wcast-qual` and `-Wwrite-strings` (which at least proved that gcc agreed).

Comment: You should really use `TMPDIR` instead of `/tmp/` as well. So there isn't really any easy way to switch out `tempnam` (which actually check `TMPDIR`).